# Unable to obtain correct token for authentication Azure SQL db using windows authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am trying to authenticate user for Azure SQL db access using windows authentication with token generation. I have followed the approach specified in blogs. Below is the code snippet.

```
var conn = (SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection();
conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

The problem I am facing is in the token generation. The token does get generated but authentication fails. When I tried to decode the token, it shows wrong user account. Instead of taking my corporate email, it was taking one of my personal email id. I looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution to pass username.

Comment: The `AzureServiceTokenProvider` gets the credentials of the account which login the VS in local, can you make sure you login with the correct account?

Comment: Understood. You are right, I was using different account in VS local. But the catch is, it's not working in App service as well.

Comment: Because in the web app, it uses the credential of the web app MSI, you need to [enable the MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity) of web app, and configure all the permissions of the MSI(service principal) like your user account. Then it wil work.

Comment: Could my comment solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry for not responding, i didn't got time to test the scenario. I will confirm once tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AzureServiceTokenProvider` gets the credentials of the account which login the VS in local, so you need to login with the correct account.

In the web app, it uses the credential of the web app MSI, you need to [enable the MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity) of web app, and configure all the permissions of the MSI(service principal) like your user account.

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-to-azure-services).

Comment: Thank you Wang. By adding the service principal the web app was able to connect to SQL db.